# How do I "tune my program" to get relative errors down to E-10?

Tags: swift, recursion, precision, numerical-methods

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggDcF.png)

I wrote a recursive program to calculate the first 26 values of the spherical Bessel functions for a given input `x`. The program seems to start to accumulate relatively large errors at `j_8(x)`. Here is the output of some code that found the relative errors based on some known high precision spherical Bessel function values for the first 25 SBF's (`l=0 to l=24`):

```
5.27753443514687e-16
9.21595688945492e-16
3.02006896635059e-15
7.62720601251909e-14
4.57824286846449e-12
4.42939097671948e-10
6.23673401270476e-08
1.20281992792456e-05
0.00304187901758528
0.976196008573827
387.486227014647
186360.170424407
106776056.913571
71856241567.0684
56117385601216.0
5.03357079061797e+16
5.13915094291702e+19
5.92532834322625e+22
7.6613338261931e+25
1.10398479254694e+29
1.76304629085447e+32
3.10469930465156e+35
6.00134333269024e+38
1.26807670217943e+42
2.91783063679757e+45
```

As you can see, after the `j_8(x)` value the error is starting to increase. The problem simply states that I should "tune" my program to get the error down to `E-10`, but how do I do this? I'm completely lost...

**The code:**

```
import Foundation

var x: Double = 0.0
var j_up_val: Double = 0.0

func j_up(x_val: Double, l_val: Double) -> Double {

    if l_val == 0 {

        j_up_val = sin(x_val)/x_val

    } else if l_val == 1 {

        j_up_val = (sin(x_val)/pow(x_val,2.0)) - (cos(x_val)/x_val)

    } else if l_val == 2 {

        j_up_val = ((2*(l_val-1)+1)/x_val) * ((sin(x_val)/pow(x_val,2.0)) - cos(x_val)/x_val) - sin(x_val)/x_val

    } else {

        let l2: Double = l_val - 1
        let l3: Double = l_val - 2

        j_up_val = ((2*(l_val-1)+1)/x_val)*j_up(x_val: x, l_val: l2) - j_up(x_val: x, l_val: l3)
    }

    return j_up_val

}

x = 1
print("x:", x)
for i in 0...25 {

    var i_double: Double = 0.0
    i_double = Double(i)

    print("l:", i)
    print(j_up(x_val: x, l_val: i_double))
    print(" \n")

}
print("**********************")
```

Comment: Try returning zero if x_val goes under FLT_EPSILON. In a sense that adds more error, but they might cancel out.

Comment: What is FLT_EPSILON?

Comment: Wait, also I'm not changing the value of `x_val`. It's always `x_val=1` for this test case.

Comment: Generally you get numerical instability when dividing by a value close to zero. FLT_EPSILON is the smallest value you can add to a 32 bit float equal to 1.0 to obtain a  result larger than 1.0. So very small in absolute terms, but quite large in double precision terms. It's a common hack to use it as a termination condition. However that isn't the problem here.

Comment: I tied printing both `FLT_EPSILON` and `__FLT_EPSILON__` to see if the sandbox I'm using understands what this is but both times I get an error: `use of unresolved identifier`. Do I need to import a library of some sort?

Comment: It will be 1.192092896e-07. Apparently you need something called "Darwin" but it's hardly worth it for one identifier.